# Google Analytics Landing Page Spam

Tags: google-analytics

one of my clients websites shows a wrong URL when I open the landing page in a new browser. Note that the source/ medium is organic. The sub pages that shows in my landing page column are right, but when I open it to see and check the website, it redirects me to a spammy website or what i believe is one of our competitors trying to copy our site. I have no idea how does it happen, i check all the property settings and everything is fine. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google Analytics spam and is not programing related. Author should try posting on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/